# Insertion function showing exception on counting records for specific cnic

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

am getting this strange error in my c# program having an insertion function. The function is like this: take the value of cnic from the textbox and check it against column cnic in table to check the count of that cnic existing in the table for that specific cnic. The purpose is basically to avoid the duplication of cnic's in that column. when the query is being run i get an exception that is:

**The conversion of the nvarchar value '3410122878898' overflowed an int column**

This value **'3410122878898'** does not concern the working of current value as am entering **67784**. However **'3410122878898'** is my last row in the same table. This is actually strange for me as my table has datatypes as follows:

```
[v_id]          BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [cnic]          NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [name]          NVARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
    [Gender]        NCHAR (10)     NULL,
    [Address]       NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [email]         NVARCHAR (40)  NULL,
    [mob_no]        NVARCHAR (20)  NULL,
    [employer]      NVARCHAR (5)   NOT NULL,
    [mnl_reg_chk]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [black_lst_chk] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_visitor_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([v_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [unique_cnic] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([cnic] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_visitor_visitor_company] FOREIGN KEY ([employer]) REFERENCES [dbo].[visitor_company] ([comp_id])
```

The only int near to cnic is the first column the id one that is primary key as well as auto increment.

Here is my code which is throwing the exception:

```
String L_query = "Select COUNT(cnic) from visitor where visitor.cnic=" + cnic;
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = L_query;
            String count = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

The execution of line **String count =...** right above is where exception happens that i mentioned first. Kindly help me resolve the issue! I have explained question to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: what happens if you execute "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..."?

Comment: Shouldn't cnic be quoted in query? isn't `[cnic] NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,`?

Comment: even better would be to use parameters (SqlParameter) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `3410122878898` is string you need use quotes.

```
String L_query = 
string.Format("Select COUNT(cnic) from visitor where visitor.cnic='{0}'", cnic);
```

Comment: Don't forget to filter _cinic_ or use SqlParameter as unfiltered is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

could 3410122878898 really be the number of records returned? then you should use COUNT_BIG instead of COUNT ...